# Definition of period in modern times

Tags: newtonian-gravity

In a [recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710624/computing-newtons-gravitational-constant-from-cavendishs-data) I was trying to calculate the Newtonian constant G from Cavendish's period (N) and number of divisions (B) of the deflection of the arm by Newtonian gravity.

My calculation was way off. But I figured that I needed to halve Cavendish's B, because what he really gave in his summary table was 2B ([page 520 of his paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstl.1798.0022)).

But that was not enough, I got the correct result only when I doubled N.

Cavendish computed the period as the "round trip" of the arm, that is, he calculated the "rest point" of the arm and then he calculated the time when the arm came back to the same rest point.

My question is this: In the equation I use, [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment), the period is defined as

$$
T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{\kappa}}
$$

Is this half period? Meaning, the motion of the pendulum arm from one extreme to the other? If so this would be half of what Cavendish calls "period." Correct?

What do you think?

Comment: I have posted an answer with [your original question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710624/computing-newtons-gravitational-constant-from-cavendishs-data)